# Wordpress - just refresh blog archive by new query

Tags: wp-query

There are some ways to re-query main posts loop. For example - `query_posts($query)`. Samples shown in Codex provide me with printing new stuff in cycle `have_rows`.

Sorry, but I don't want print something new - just let me to refresh currently showing posts at blog archive page (main loop).

But how to refresh blog archive page with new query results?

Comment: You are trying to add filters there for blog posts?

Comment: Which filters do you mean?

Comment: Some filters for WP_Query ? If so, which one(s)